# HTTP 401 Azure Terraform Action Group sending log search alert to Azure Function

Tags: azure, function, terraform

I have a weird problem:

I have an action group in Azure that is deployed via this terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "example" {
  name                = "test1mag"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  short_name          = "blabla"

  email_receiver {
    name                    = "test1email"
    email_address           = "emailaddress@emailreceiver.com"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
  azure_function_receiver {
    name                     = "test1function"
    function_app_resource_id = module.function_app_zis.function_app_id
    http_trigger_url         = "https://function4711.azurewebsites.net"
    function_name            = "httptrigger"
    use_common_alert_schema  = true
  }
  depends_on = [module.function_app_zis]
}
```

The deployment is OK and when I go into the Azure portal and click on "Test Action Group" within "edit action group", I am getting an email and this part is absolutely fine.

On the function side I am getting no error, it's looking like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcD6e.png)

but **the function app is not triggered. It's doing nothing.**

The funny thing is: When I am editing the settings for the action type "function" in the portal and simply click on OK and SAVE CHANGES, try it again and it's working!!!

I literally **did not change anything**, but simply confirmed in the portal what had already been deployed by terraform.

One remark, because I guess this is where the problem comes from: The function in this functionapp is not deployed by terraform code, it is delivered via a zip file with python code included. Therefore the name of the function, in this case "httptrigger" is the name of the folder in the zip file, where the .py and .json files are located.

This is also the reason why I was using this line in the code

`function_name            = "httptrigger"`

although I would definitely have loved to hand over the function name as a variable instead of a string, but I actually do not know how to do this....

My suspicion is that the name of the function or whatever else is confirmed in Azure with my manual re-confirmation of the settings in the action group and has not been accepted correctly before.

Anyone can help here?

I am expecting that the function app is triggered from the action group, which is not the case if deployed with my terraform code.

Answer (score 0):

> To hand over the function name as a variable instead of a string: -

You can store the `function_name` in a variable file and then use it in the `function_name` property of the `azure_function_receiver` block in the action group resource.

`var.tf`:

```bash
variable "function_name" {
   type=String
   default = "function name"
}
```

And access it in `main.tf` as `function_name = var.function_name` under `resource` block.

**Alternatively** in my environment, I tried using a `data` block in the code to access the already deployed `function_app` and it worked perfectly.

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example"{
    name = "<resourcegroup name>"
}
data "azurerm_windows_function_app" "example" {
    name = "fnappuovh4pk4fceb6"
    resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "example" {
  name                = "test1mag"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "p0action"

  email_receiver {
    name                    = "test1email"
    email_address           = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
  azure_function_receiver {
    name                     = "test1function"
    function_app_resource_id = data.azurerm_windows_function_app.example.id
    http_trigger_url         = "https://fnappuovh4pk4fceb6.azurewebsites.net"
    function_name            = "HttpTrigger1"
    use_common_alert_schema  = true
  }
}
```

***Executed terraform init, plan and apply as shown:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Action group deployed successfully:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's great indeed, but it doesn't solve my real problem. Click on "Test" in the action group and tell me if you both get an email AND the function app is triggered. Because that is what's not working here.
When I re-confirm the settings in the portal, it's doing it, but I would expect that terraform's deployment is sufficient already...

Comment: Yes it got fired and sent an alert in an email as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/QrJFGnM.png). @Odelys

Comment: I have the explanation for the misbehavior on my side now as I had also put on a request at Microsoft:
The http_trigger_url also has to have the code (=the function key) to be added like this:
"https://${module.function_app_zis.trigger_url}/api/httptrigger?code=${data.external.function_key.result["function_key"]}"

This code is added when I re-confirm it in the portal, that was the reason why it was working the second time.

Now this problem is solved.

Anyway thanks for your help.